# Excel data set with non-numeric data - filtering? Counting? What?

Tags: excel, windows, excel-formula

I'm dealing with a massive data set about academic book publications from a research e-repository, with over 100 000 rows. I've been asked to pull the number of publications per Publisher and create a Top 20 using the data set. We're only interested in counting titles from the Social Sciences classification. But the data set has allowed for up to 4 different classifications, and thus if it's a Social Sciences publication, it could be listed in Classification 1, 2, 3, or 4 columns. For eg:

[Example of Publishers and the Classification columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PC7J1.png)

So I want the final product to count rows where there's a value of "Social Sciences" in Columns B:E, and then group those rows by the Value in Column A. I feel like the answer is right in front of my face but I just can't see it. I've tried pivot tables, filters, COUNTIF, COUNTA, and nothing seems to be giving me what I want in a clean way. And I know a distant colleague did it with the same type of data set 2 years ago but I haven't heard back from them yet.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: My attempts at advanced filtering seem to get rid of everything. Here's an example:

[Advanced Filter attempt 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLjpx.png)

Comment: Have you tried summing 4 countif formulas or grouping using advanced filter?

Comment: @Jeeped I'm just experimenting with advanced filter now. I'm hoping that will do the trick but if it doesn't I'll keep this thread up.

Comment: For OR on B:E, put *Social Sciences* on different rows in the criteria.

Comment: It didn't work. I had a go like you said, and it's just hidden every single cell and says 0 records match the criteria. I've got a screen shot of it.

Comment: I just tested it by filtering rows that where the B column contains "Social Sciences" and again it turns up zero results. I'm starting to think there's something wrong with my data.

Comment: You probably need a wildcard `*` in the publisher column. [See this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5b7N.gif).

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out the reason that my initial filtering wasn't working was because I was forgetting the '=' alongside the text requirement. Silly, I know, but it's fixed now and works beautifully. Thanks for helping me talk it out.

Comment: This response would benefit from sample data paired with expected results (as would your original question). Unlike your original question, you should also include a visual clued to your solution. I'm interested in how this works around the need for a wildcard publisher.